# The mapped local path exceeded the limit of 248 characters for the directory or 259 for the directory and file name

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to create a branch and getting the local path exceeded the limit. We are using TFS 2015 version 14.0.23128.0.

I thought the character limit was changed to 400.  Is there a configuration to increase limit to 400 characters?  Is there a workaround besides decreasing the folder structure/file name?

Comment: Check this blog: https://alistairbmackay.wordpress.com/2014/01/15/tfs-path-too-long-problems/ for the explanation of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check UserVoices [Fix 260 character file name length limitation](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/2156195-fix-260-character-file-name-length-limitation) and [Fix 260 character file name length limitation](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/4954037-fix-260-character-file-name-length-limitation), the limitation from the BCL for the basic file manipulation functionality (CRUD) has been removed. You can find more details here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/02/announcing-net-framework-4-6-2/